# Setting Position of SKSpriteNode in Swift 4

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, cgpoint

So below, I have one SKSpriteNode image that I'm also animating using Texture Atlas along SKAction.animate to animate through one of my texture arrays. When I first run the app, the image shows up directly in the center of the screen and animates like it should. But when I try to position the node through CGPoint, it doesn't move. I've even tried, "**CGPoint(x: 0, y: -self.height / 2)**" because I want the image to show up on the very bottom center of the screen but doesn't work. Sometimes when I run the app on my iPhone, the image isn't even there sometimes and I have rerun the application. I must be doing something really wrong but my code seems right?

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    
    let background = SKSpriteNode(texture:SKTexture(imageNamed: "background"))

    var person = SKSpriteNode()

    let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "people")
    var textureArray = [SKTexture]()
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        self.background.zPosition = 0.0
        self.addChild(background)
        
        person = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "person1.png")
        person.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
        self.person.zPosition = 1.0
        person.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 129)
        person = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: atlas.textureNames[0])
        
        for i in 1...atlas.textureNames.count {
            let Name = "person\(i).png"
            textureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: Name))
        }
        
        let myAnimation = SKAction.animate(with: textureArray, timePerFrame: 0.1)
        self.addChild(person)
        person.run(SKAction.repeatForever(myAnimation))

    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I suspect I know where the problem could be.

You have these three lines in different places of your code:

```
var person = SKSpriteNode()

person = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: “person1.png")

person = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: atlas.textureNames[0])
```

All these lines create a **new** SKSpriteNode and assign a reference to that new sprite node to be held by a variable named `person`.

In your code, you change the position of the 2nd `person` node. Then you create a 3rd `person` node. This means that the position you set earlier won't have any effect on the 3rd `person` node, since only the 2nd `person` position was changed.

I would recommend to create only one `person` node, and thereafter set its position, zposition, size, etc. To fix this, consider replacing `var person = SKSpriteNode()` with `var person: SKSpriteNode?`. Then also replace the line `person = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: “person1.png")` with `person = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: atlas.textureNames[0])`, and of course remove the line `person = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: atlas.textureNames[0])` that occurs just before the `for` loop.

Since `person` is now defined as an optional, it will now need to be accessed as `person?`, or as `person!` in cases where you are sure it can't be nil. Xcode will show you where you need to add the extra `?`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked! Appreciate it, I changed the position to "person?.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -size.height / 2)" but the image is slightly under the screen. I need to pull it back up somehow

Comment: You're welcome! Add half the person's height to the y position. That will make sure that the bottom y of person aligns perfectly with the bottom y position of scene (assuming anchor points of scene and person are both set to CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5).

Comment: Works like a charm, truly appreciate you so much! Always been grateful for individuals like you.

Comment: I would do `lazy var person = SKSpriteNode(texture:textureNamed(person))`  This allows for person to be created only once at the time it is needed, and allows you to properly use the texture atlas